# Sein gesagt oder haben gesagt?

Tags: standard-german

Ich habe eine wichtige Frage. Können wir das Verb "sagen" mit *sein* benutzen, wenn wir kein Adjektiv haben? Z.B.:

> Ich bin gesagt.

Comment: Bitte schreibe Hauptwörter groß und auch am Satzanfang. Wenn es ein Problem mit der Eingabe über ein Smartphone ist, warte, bis Du an einem PC sitzt. Ein Post wird nur einmal geschrieben, aber 100x gelesen. Man sollte daher die Arbeit ins Schreiben, nicht ins Lesen investieren.

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb *sagen* bildet zwar das Perfekt mit *haben*, nicht mit *sein*; aber es verbindet sich mit *sein* zum sogenannten *Zustandspassiv* ([canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Genera/Zustandspass.html)). In den folgenden Sätzen ist das Subjekt **fett**, das Objekt *kursiv* markiert.

> Ich rede, bis **ich** *alles* gesagt habe, was ich sagen will.
> Ich rede, bis **alles** gesagt ist.
>
> [*Was* **wir** gesagt haben] *(Obj.)* haben **wir** gesagt.
> [**Was** gesagt ist] *(Subj.)* ist gesagt.
>
> *Eins* möchte **ich** dir sagen: ...
> **Eins** sei dir gesagt: ...

Wie die Beispiele zeigen, ist beim Zustandspassiv *ich* kein geeignetes Subjekt, da normalerweise Sachen (und nicht Personen) gesagt werden.

Bei der zweiten Gruppe von Beispielen tritt die gesuchte Struktur doppelt auf; die eingebetteten Sätze fungieren selber als Objekt (im Aktiv) bzw. Subjekt (im Passiv).

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt allerdings

> Das ist nicht gesagt.

Es bedeutet, dass über eine Angelegenheit noch nicht das letzte Wort gesprochen, dass sie noch nicht entschieden ist, oder dass sich die Dinge anders entwickeln können:

> Die deutschen Autobauer werden auch bei ihren deutschen Kunden nicht um erhebliche Entschädigungszahlungen herumkommen. - *Das ist nicht gesagt. Jedenfalls beschäftigen sie eine ganze Armada von Anwälten damit, um das zu vermeiden.*

Answer (score -1):

Es gibt die exotische Möglichkeit, dass Du aus der phantastischen Perspektive eines Wortes berichtest, das gesagt wird und jetzt über sich Auskunft gibt, etwa zu einem anderen Wort, das noch nicht gesagt ist, sondern nur gedacht.

In allen üblichen Situationen sagt man schlicht "Ich sage", aber in Kombination, etwa "Ich sage ab.", "Ich sage Hallo.", "Ich sage, dass Hertha noch absteigt!", "Ich sage: 'Geh mir aus der Sonne!'" oder "Ich sage etwas.". Für die Vergangenheit: "Ich habe gesagt ...", nicht "Ich war gesagt ...".

Ohne Zusätze sagt man nicht "Ich sage.", sondern "Ich spreche.", "Ich rede." oder etwas anderweitig spezifischeres wie "Ich brülle." oder "Ich flüster."